# Water main construction. Find the angle using vectors.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vector-spaces

A water main is to be constructed with a $12.5$​% grade in the north direction and a $25$​% grade in the east direction. Determine the angle $\theta$ required in the water main for the turn from north to east.

Comment: i am having a hard time determining the vectors needed to solve for cos-1 to find the angle

Comment: If you click "edit" under the question you should be able to insert new text explaining where you had a hard time. That's usually better than putting the explanation in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

We have to know what an $n\%$ grade means. I suppose it means the vertical "rise" of the pipe is $n\%$ of the horizontal "run" of the pipe; the rise and run are two legs of a right triangle, and the actual pipe is the hypotenuse.

And we probably want a coordinate system whose axes are parallel to the directions "north", "east", and "up". So if the $x$ axis is "east"
and the $z$ axis is "up",
a pipe going due east with a $25\%$ grade will go $0.25$ units in the
$z$ direction for every $1$ unit in the $x$ direction.
A typical vector in that direction is $[1, 0, 0.25]^T$.
That's not a unit vector, so you have to remember to account for
the vector's magnitude.